# Start App in localhost with IIS Express - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I have a problem. I want to start a new instance of my App from Visual Studio (C #).

It starts at http://localhost:54619/. The problem is that when starting, a loop is created in the `Application_BeginRequest()` method of the class Global.asax.cs and it never comes out of there. I try to redirect it with `Response.RedirectToRoute("Default")`, but it does not work. I can't get out of that method.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
    Response.Redirect("~/Principal");
    }
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC, IIS Express.

Comment: "a loop is created in the Application_BeginRequest () method of the class Global.asax.cs" - can you show us your Application_BeginRequest code then? You can edit it into the question.

Comment: I added it to the question. However the problem is not the code, but the method does not stop invoking.

Comment: you are redirecting every request to a new place.  of course it's going to go into an infinite loop.  What are you trying to actually achieve.

Comment: I want start the application from the controller that I already have configured.

Comment: Check where you are before you try to redirect.  You can also set a start url in the project settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `Application_BeginRequest()` as it name states is executed always when your application gets a request. Then in that method you respond to the client that it should go instead to `~/Principal` path. When the client recieves this response, it will create a new request that will eventially get the same response. You wanted to redirect the requests to your default controller. You should do this by registering a route to that controller. The MVC template for ASP.NET has an example for this:

1. Create a function that registers the desired routes

   ```
   public class RouteConfig
       {
           public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
           {
               routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

               routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "Default",
                   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );
           }
       }
   ```
2. Invoke the function in Global.asax.cs

   ```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
       {
           protected void Application_Start()
           {
               AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
               FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
               RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
               BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
           }
       }
   ```

Now your app should redirect the user to a controller named "Home" and to its action called "Index", if no other route fits the request.